# Getting Text value from element using beautifulsoup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am making python script which getting text data from online site.
this is simple web scraping script and the language is only python.
I don't use selenium and use only beautifulsoup.
and I can **scrape** text from `<p>` or `<div>` or even `<h>` and `<a>`
but when I try to get text from `<td>`, the code is not working.
I shared my code below.

```
        from threading import Thread
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        from lxml import etree

        detailPage = requests.get(SUBURL, headers=HEADERS)
        detailsoup = BeautifulSoup(detailPage.content, "html.parser")
        detaildom = etree.HTML(str(detailsoup))
        name = detaildom.xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"]')[0].text

        asin = detaildom.xpath('//*[@id="productDetails_detailBullets_sections1"]/tbody/tr[1]/td')[0].text
```

here, getting name is working, asin return empty string.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a helpful description of your problem. Write the HTML out to a file and post a relevant snippet as part of your question.

Comment: What's the URL? is the page loaded dynamically?

Comment: url is https://www.amazon.co.jp//-/en/Ohyama-Powerful-Ventilation-Low-Noise-Circulator/dp/B079LWYC17/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A4%E3%83%9E%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC18%E7%95%B3%2C&qid=1626446542&sr=8-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the table by its ID `productDetails_detailBullets_sections1` and find the `<td>` which contains the "ASIN".

Using a CSS selector:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
print("ASIN:", soup.select_one("#productDetails_db_sections tr > td").get_text(strip=True))
```

Using `.find()`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
table_info = soup.find(id="productDetails_detailBullets_sections1").find("tr")

print("ASIN:", table_info.find('td').get_text(strip=True))
```

Output (in both solutions):

```
ASIN: B079LWYC17
```